# Angular RXjs Websocket

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, rxjs

```
Service code.

import { webSocket, WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/webSocket';
export class SocketioService {

  private socket$: WebSocketSubject<any>;
  private dataObs$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  private socket;
  constructor() {

    this.socket$ = webSocket('ws://some url');
  }


  sendCmd(query) {

    this.socket$.next(query);

    this.socket$.subscribe(message => {
   //////// here i get duplicate responses on subsequent invocation from other components
      this.dataObs$.next(message);

    });

    
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.dataObs$.asObservable();
  }

}

appcomponent:

  this.dataservice.sendCmd('abc');
      
this.dataservice.getData().subscribe( data => {
if(data!=null){

    console.log(data); 
}

});

y component:

      this.dataservice.sendCmd('xyz');      
     this.dataservice.getData().subscribe( data => {
      if(data!=null){
          console.log(data);
      }
      });
```

Issue is when i send second command , in socket subscribe method response is coming twice and gets piled up

Example --- first command --- 1 response comes
-------  second command --- 4 response (2 for first command and 2 for second command) --- duplicates
--------third command ------------  6 response (3 for first command, 3 for second command, 3 for third command) -- duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you create a new subscription each time your `sendCmd` method is called and you never unsubscribe from each of those subscriptions.

You don't actually need the `dataObs$` subject:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

@Injectable({ provideIn: 'root' })
export class SocketioService {
  private readonly socket$ = webSocket('ws://some url');
  
  public readonly data$ = this.socket$.pipe(
    share(), // to make sure only one subscription is created
  );

  public sendCmd(cmd) {
    this.socket$.next(cmd);
  }
}
```

And when you want to subscribe to the data use:

```
this.dataService.data$.subscribe(/* ... */);
```

Comment: public readonly data$ = this.socket$.pipe(
    share(), // to make sure only one subscription is created
  );--- Can you please put full code for this function

Comment: `share` should be imported from `rxjs/operators`, i'll add it to the answer

Comment: thank you. one more questiion, how do we use this from component. Can you please paste component code to receive this response